# Definition by Abstraction in Axiomatic Set Theory by Suppes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

I am just starting self-studying Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes. I have a doubt on the definition by abstraction.

[image]

Just to give some context, Suppes defines a set as

> $y $ is a set $\leftrightarrow \exists x\in y\ \vee\ y=0$ (empty set)

I found the first element in Def 11's disjunction is enough. If $y$ is not an empty set, we don't go to the second element; if $y$ is indeed an empty set, then for any $x$, $x\in y$ is not true, which requires $\phi(x)$ cannot be satsified. Conversely, if $\phi(x)$ is not satisfiable, then $x\notin y$ for every $x$. Then, $y$ is an empty set. This already expresses out intuitive understanding.

I further found the second element confusing. Suppose indeed $\phi(x)$ is not satisfiable, in which case our intuition tells us $y=0$ (empty set). I can indeed find $B=0$ (empty set) too. $\forall x\ \neg \phi(x)$, and $\forall x\ \neg x\in B$. Thus, I conclude there exists $B=\phi$, $\forall x,x\in B\leftrightarrow \phi(x)$.

This contradicts the definition of Suppes. Am I wrong with the reasonings in both paragraphs above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is defining the "set-builder" operator: $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ that "maps" a predicate (a formula $\varphi$ with free variable $x$) into a *term* (i.e. the "name" of an object).

It is well-known that the so-called unrestricted Comprehension Principle is inconsistent [see §1.3]: thus, not every predicate can meaningfully define a set.

The author uses the definitional schema illustrated at page 19 with the $x/y=z$ example.

Going back to Definition 11, the author illustrates it at page 34.

There are two possible cases:

> *(i)* either there is a set $A$ such that $(\forall x)(x \in A \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$,

in which case we **define** that the "set-builder" operator maps formula $\varphi$ to that set, or

> *(ii)* there is no set $B$ such that $(\forall x)(x \in B \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$,

in which case we "arbitrarily" **define** that the "set-builder" operator maps formula $\varphi$ to the empty set.

---

Maybe your confusion is due to the incorrect way of reading the definition:

> "if $y$ is not an empty set, we don't go to the second element; if $y$ is indeed an empty set, then for any $x, x∈y$ is not true, which requires $\varphi(x)$ cannot be satisfied.

We are defining $y$, i.e. we have to start from the formula and "manufacture" the corresponding set.

Regarding:

> I further found the second element confusing. Suppose indeed $\varphi(x)$ is not satisfiable,...

The issue is not the satisfiability of the formula; consider the discussion about Russell's paradox (page 6).

Into the formula $(\forall x) (x \in y \leftrightarrow \lnot (x \in x))$we are using $\lnot (x \in x)$ as $\varphi(x)$ and the formula is indeed satisfiable: $\lnot (\emptyset \in \emptyset)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think Suppes handles the Unrestricted Comprehension Principle **after** the definition of abstraction. In other words, by writing {--:--} does not automatically imply the set exists. But here, my confusion is at the empty set. Consider your second point "there is no set  such that." I do not think this can happen. Suppose $\varphi(x)$ is not satisfiable (e.g., $x=1 \wedge x=2$), I can indeed find a set $B=0$ s.t. $(\forall x)(x\in B\leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$. Thus, I will never go to the second element of the disjunction?

Comment: @Mou - as said above, **it is not true** that for every predicate there is the corresponding set. Obviously, if $\varphi(x)$ is **not** satisfiable (e.g. $x \ne x$) it will be mapped to the empty set. But the issue is with case of *satisfiable* formulas, like that used fro Russell's set.

Comment: Hi @Mauro, in the paragraph after Def 11, Suppes says "The point of the second member of the disjunction of the definiens is to put $\{x: \varphi(x)\}$ equal to the empty set if there is no non-empty set having as members just those entities with property $\varphi$. It looks like Suppes is handling non-satisfiable $\varphi$. But I am trying to understand what you mean. Are you saying by this definition $\{x:\varphi(x)\equiv x\in x\}=$empty set by using the second condition of Def 11? Thanks.

Comment: @Mou - if you want to use the formula $\{ x \mid x \in x \}$, you have **first** to prove that a set $y$ exists such that $(\forall x) (x \in y \leftrightarrow (x \in x) \}$. The author will prove (see page 54) that $A \notin A$. Thus, **at that point** we will conclude that $y$ exists and it is the empty set.

Comment: Hi @Mauro, I now totally see that by Suppes a paradoxical set is an empty set. This is given by Theorem 50. $0=\{x:x=x\}$. But this really upsets me (who knows naive set theory) in another way, as this time when we say $\{x:\varphi(x)\}=$empty set, it's possible that $\varphi(x)$ is not satisfiable, or it might be the case that $\{x:\varphi(x)\}=$ is paradoxical. Not sure if this is standard. By Wikipedia's explanation of ZF set theory, it is forbidden to define {x:\varphi(x)}.

Comment: @Mou - Yes; Th.50 is one of the main diff between Naitve ST and Axiomatic ST. In Naive, we have no restriction to Comprehension and thus we use freely the set-builder operator defining $V= \{ x \mid x=x \}$ (the "universe"). If we do so in Axiomatic STR, we can use Separation to produce Russell's set: $(\forall x)(x \in R \leftrightarrow (x \in V \land \lnot (x \in x)))$ (see Th.41).