# *Updated* Problem showing General Distributive Law In Suppes Axiomatic Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

In Suppes's Axiomatic Set Theory, we are asked to prove the following:

Theorem 84 $A \cap \bigcup B = \bigcup_{C \in B} (A \cap C)$

Definition Schema:
$\bigcup_{x \in A} t(x) = \bigcup \{y : \exists x(y = t(x)\,\&\,x \in A\}$
where $t(x)$ denotes a term schema.

I'm stuck on the part showing that $A\cap \bigcup B \subset \bigcup_{C \in B} (A \cap B)$ where I am at so far:

Let $x \in A \cap \bigcup B$. Then $x\in A$ & $x\in D$ & $D\in B$. So, $(x\in A \cap D)\& (D \in B)$. To show that $x\in \bigcup_{C \in B} (A \cap C)$ we need to show that $\exists D'(x \in D' \space \land$ $D' \in\{y : \exists C(y = A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B) \}$.

The issue and problem I am running into is showing $D'\in\{y:\exists C(y = A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B)\}$.

The appropriate $D'$ seems to be $A \cap D$, since $A\cap D = A\cap D\;\&\; D\in B$ is true, i.e., $\varphi(A \cap D)$ is true. But this doesn't allow us to infer  $A \cap D \in \{y : \exists C(y = A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B) \}$, since it's not true that $\varphi(A \cap D) \implies A \cap D \in \{y : \exists C(y = A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B) \}$. We can only make that inference if we have either $\{y : \exists C(y = A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B) \}$ is not empty or $\exists Z \forall x(x \in Z \iff \exists C(x= A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B)$ as per the definition by abstraction.

Suppes Definition for abstraction notation $\{ x\mid \varphi(x) \}$ is given here: [Definition by Abstraction in Axiomatic Set Theory by Suppes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733730/definition-by-abstraction-in-axiomatic-set-theory-by-suppes).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141031/discussion-on-question-by-jcal-updated-problem-showing-general-distributive-la).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now figured this out, We need the power set axiom introduced in the next section as indicated by the Hint in the Dover edition (which I am not using) this hint is not in the original edition.

From this we can deduce. $\exists Z \forall x(x \in Z \iff \exists C(x= A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B)$ as per the definition by abstraction, and Whence the desired inference. I knew something wrong was going on here in the edition I have.

Answer (score 0):

For every $p$ we have

$p\in A\cap (\bigcup B) \iff$

$(p\in A)\land (p\in\bigcup B)\iff$

$(p\in A)\land (\exists C\in B\,(p\in C)) \iff$

$\exists C\in B\,(p\in A\land p\in C) \iff$

$\exists C\in B\,(p\in A\cap C)\iff$

$p\in\bigcup_{C\in B} \,(A\cap C).$

Comment: The last equivalence is incorrect ‘$\implies$‘ For this present theory. see updated question

Comment: The proof does not explain the problem that I am stuck on, which is the basis of my question. See updated post.

Comment: From: Let $x \in A \cap \bigcup B$ we need to show that $x\in \bigcup_{C \in B} (A \cap C)$ to do this we need to show that $\exists D'(x \in D' \space \land$ $D' \in\{y : \exists C(y = A \cap C \space \& \space C \in B) \}$.

How?

Comment: I am correct for this theory that last equivalence is incorrect.